# Minimal implementation of GPS identification algorithm from NESSIE project?

Tags: implementation

I'm studying GPS, asymmetric identification scheme from the [NESSIE project](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/). I found a bunch of helpful information about it in the [original submission](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/workshop/submissions.html), they even mention minimal implementation examples (in C/GPS-C.pdf of submission archive). But they only mention them and provide instructions on how to compile them, source files themselves aren't present in submission. I was wondering does someone know where I can find these files (or other implementations)? I tried googling, but it seems extremely a few documents are mentioning GPS, and none of them have any source code.

Sadly, I'm not good enough in math&cryptography to implement them myself. It's a lot easier for me to understand algorithm reading implementation code than papers. Examples in Python/JavaScript/Java/C(++) will be extremely helpful, but any other language will be fine too.

Also, I was wondering does it somehow related to [Global Positioning System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) or it's just a coincidence?